# Woocommerce reports an error in the CHECKOUT form, error 2 ok 0

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

when creating an order in Woocomerce, after placing the goods in the basket, filling out the form at the checkout, name, address, etc., after sending the form, it says an error, a red exclamation mark and 2 ok 0 error, it does not send the order with the form, please, what could be the problem?

I don't know how to proceed, I burned some plugins

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What works for me was to update php to 8 and i have removed plugin České služby.